# MongoDB/Mongoose:Getting incorrect distance with geoNear method using geoJSON

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson

I have defined my schema as

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  coords: {
    type: [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
  },
});
```

geoJSON object defined as

```
var geoOptions = {
    spherical: true,
    maxDistance: 5000,
    distanceMultiplier : 0.001,
    num: 10
}
loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function(error, results, stats){//do stuff});
```

where loc is my model instance and my point is

```
var point = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [lng,lat]
};
```

I have two documents in my database with coords

```
"coords" : [
    18.9164127,
    72.8245292
]

"coords" : [
    18.935197,
    72.8249342
]
```

I am getting the distance between these two as 0.619 km where as it should be more than 2 km.
Can't figure out where I am doing mistake. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be okay, are you inserting the coords in the format [longitude, latitude] ? That order matters and is the order used by mongo to perform queries using geoNear.

Comment: Yes I already checked with the order.It is in correct format.

Comment: But I see you have "coords" : [18.9164127, 72.8245292], when it should be  "coords" : [72.8245292, 18.9164127]

Comment: So here is the url extracted from google maps, https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/18%C2%B056'06.7%22N+72%C2%B049'29.8%22E/@18.9353867,72.8226975,915m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d18.935197!4d72.8249342?hl=en

Comment: Sure, I know it is a valid coordinate and is in the order [latitude, longitude]. The problem here is that when you store that data into "coords", it must be in the **[longitude, latitude]** order because this is how mongo works. If you insert the coords as usual [latitude, longitude] it will not work as spected. Here you can see the documentation about this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#spherical

Comment: my bad! I didn't check the value but looked at order of keys stored in db.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: in case of something like `location: {longitude: 0.0, latitude:0.0}` how do we ensure order??